# Limit and integral with trigonometric function

Tags: integration, limits

Calculate $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{2n\pi}^{2(n+1)\pi} x\ln(x)\cos x\mathrm{d}x.$$

Firstly, I tried to solve it by parts, but I think this is not a good option. Then, I tried to use the average theorem, but $\cos x$ isn't positive for the whole interval and the other options don't help me too much, I guess. Please help me!

Comment: Hint. Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma.

Comment: @VonNeumann How does RLL help?

Comment: Hint: Integrate by parts twice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate by parts twice.  $\int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi} xln(x)cosxdx=xln(x)sinx\big]_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}-\int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}(1+ln(x))sinxdx$.  Since $sin(n\pi)=0$, the expression is $-\int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}(1+ln(x))sinxdx=cosx(1+ln(x))\big]_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}+\int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\frac{cosx}{x}dx$.
The last integral $\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, so the original integral ends up as $-(2+ln(2n\pi)+ln((2n+1)\pi)\to -\infty$.

Note this is not too surprising since the term $xln(x)$ is larger in the second half of the integration interval, where the $cosx$ is negative.